# Detect message tampering without shared key and without certificate authority

Tags: public-key-infrastructure, hmac, tampering

Is it possible to detect if a message has been tampered with, without using MAC (i.e. shared key) and without using a "trusted" third party (i.e. certificate authority)?

I'm pretty sure it's not, but I would just like to be sure.

Note: I don't care if the message is read by anyone else, I just don't want them to be able to modify it along the path of transmission.

Answer (score 1):

**No** The recipient must know *something* about the sender to detect tampering. Otherwise, there is nothing to distinguish the legitimate sender from someone who is tampering.

There are a few choices for what the recipient knows:

- Shared secret key - to produce a MAC
- Sender's public key - to verify a signature
- Trusted third party's public key - to verify a certificate, and then a signature

Answer (score 1):

To *detect* tampering, you first have to *define* tampering. You are receiving a message; what would make it a "tampered" message and not the "genuine" message ?

The usual definition of tampered/genuine uses the *message source*: at one point in space-time, the message was assembled or verified by an entity *S*, who declares it correct. This is the definition of the genuine message: the sequence of bits corresponding to that operation (or inspection) from *S*. At another point in space-time (later, and possibly elsewhere), the verifier *V* wants to make sure that the message is still genuine, i.e. the very same sequence of bits that *S* saw.

**Knowledge is power:** everybody can buy the same computers, so if the source *S* can do something that an attacker *A* cannot do, then this *must* be because *S* knows some specific piece of data (cryptographers call that a "key") that *A* does not know. Otherwise, if *A* knows everything that *S* knows, then *A* can make messages of his own which are indistinguishable from genuine messages.

If that secret value (let's call it *K*) is known to both *S* and *V*, then a [MAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_authentication_code) can be used. Such a setup works only as long as *V* is not an attacker either. If *K* is known to *S* only, then it must still be amenable to reliable verification from *V*, and we enter the realm of asymmetric cryptography, with [digital signatures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_signature).

In both cases, we need some help from the context. Shared secrets don't materialize out of thin air; neither do certificates. We can have roughly the following situations and solutions:

1. *S* and *V* have met previously, or there is a secure channel to both from a trusted generator of random bits that only *S* and *V* can reach. Just use a MAC.
2. *S* and *V* share a secret, but it is of low entropy (say, a password that a human can remember). [Password-Authenticated Key Exchange](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Password-authenticated_key_agreement) protocols (e.g. [SRP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_remote_password_protocol)) can be used by *S* and *V* to expand that shared secret into a better shared *K* which resists dictionary attacks. This implies that *S* and *V* can, at one time, talk to each other and run the PAKE protocol (this does not need a secure line; it can be done over the Internet; but it still must happen at one point). Once they have a shared *K*, they use a MAC.
3. *S* generates a public/private key pair, and *V* has a way to make sure that what he sees as "public key of *S*" has not been tampered with. This allows *V* to verify any signature computed by *S*. This does not solves your problem, but moves it: detection of tampering on the "message" has been moved to detection of tampering on the public key. However, this can help, because the public/private key pair may have been generated and verified in advance, long before the message first came into existence; and such a key pair can be used to protect several (many) messages.
4. *V* knows the public key of a trusted third party *T*, which uses its private key to sign the public key of *S*. This is an extension of the previous case, and is basically what [PKI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_infrastructure) is about.

The important point in all of this is that no cryptography or other system will *create* trust. Cryptography just moves trust around. You still have to start somewhere, and that "somewhere" is the definition of what constitutes a "genuine message".

Answer (score 0):

You can use MD5, if the file is tampered with MD5 will tell you.

`man md5sum`

Comment: And how do you make sure that the md5sum hasn't been tampered with?

Comment: Yep I agree with @Adnan, the message could be changed and then the hash/digest of the message could be changed too. How would the recipient detect that?

Comment: Obviously the MD5 must be comunicated by other means. I don't know what is the purpose of this, if you want to send someone a message you can send a file with the message and provide the md5 by other means so that he can compare the received message with the md5 I have provided him. You can send the MD5 steganographied in some file in some other message, etc....

Comment: Only hypothetical at this stage.
Yes, but let's assume that all communication links are tapped/compromised (between sender and receiver).

Comment: If all links are tapped/compromised AND you can't meet that person physically then you can't agree in a way to transfer and check the received information, you can't even inform that person that you are going to use MD5 without that information being tampered with, so I see no reason for all this. If you can meet that person physically then you can agree with him what method you are going to use, you can publish MD5 sums in a webpage of your own and he can check the received messages with the MD5 on your web page. Use your imagination...